# How to enable / disable a button based on a checkbox being checked in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to add validation to my Angular app's form.

The first section of my form contains:

- 1 checkbox
- 2 radio button group's
- 1 button (which navigates to the next section of the form)

The button is to be disabled until the user checks the checkbox & chooses an option from both radio button group's.

Here is the code for my button:

```
<button
    [disabled]="
        theChkAcceptTerms.invalid || 
        theInsuredType.invalid || 
        theReportInjury.invalid
        ">
```

And here is the code for my checkbox:

```
<checkbox
    id="accept"
    heading="I accept"
    name="accept"
    value="accept"
    [(ngModel)]="chkAcceptTerms"
    required
    #theChkAcceptTerms="ngModel">
</checkbox>
```

Currently, when the page loads the button is disabled. It is only enabled once I check the checkbox, & choose an option in both radio groups.

However, if I un-check the checkbox, the button is not disabled.

Can someone please tell me how I can disable the above button if the checkbox is not checked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: please create https://stackblitz.com/ for better understanding of your source code

Comment: Try replacing `theChkAcceptTerms.invalid` with `!chkAcceptTerms` in the condition for `[disabled]`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Hi, if I do this, then the button is enabled without having to check the checkbox at all

Comment: Please note that I modified my previous comment after a few seconds. Make sure that you have the correct condition and that `chkAcceptTerms` is `false` initially.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Hey, I've added the **!** but it's still behaving the same. The button is being enabled without touching the checkbox

Comment: Are you sure that `chkAcceptTerms` is initially `false`? If so, the button will be disabled initially. Please note that you have to use `!chkAcceptTerms`, not `!theChkAcceptTerms`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the two way data binding for your controls and check them in the `disabled` attribute as

```
[disabled]="!checkBox || !radioGroup1 || !radioGroup2"
```

Check out the sample I created [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enable-button-on-valid-form)

Answer (score 4):

I used a template reference variable to connect my checkbox to the buttons disabled state:

```
<mat-checkbox #confirmed>Yes, I confirm</mat-checkbox>
<button mat-button [disabled]="!confirmed.checked">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your button must be disabled if your form is not valid then use

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!ngForm.valid">Submit</button>
```

or

```
 <button type="submit" [disabled]="ngForm.invalid">Submit</button>
```

Edited
In your Html

```
 <div class="container">
    <h1>Hero Form</h1>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
              required
              [(ngModel)]="ngForm.name" name="name">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="alterEgo">Alter Ego</label>
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="alterEgo"
              [(ngModel)]="ngForm" name="alterEgo" (ngModelChange)="changed($event)" > 
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="theInsuredType" value="theChkAcceptTerms"  [(ngModel)]="ngForm.theChkAcceptTerms"  (ngModelChange)="changed($event, 'theChkAcceptTerms')" > theChkAcceptTerms<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="theInsuredType" value="theInsuredType"   [(ngModel)]="ngForm.theInsuredType" (ngModelChange)="changed($event, 'theInsuredType')"> theInsuredType<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="theInsuredType" value="theReportInjury"  [(ngModel)]="ngForm.theReportInjury" (ngModelChange)="changed($event, 'theReportInjury')" > theReportInjury<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="theInsuredType" value="oneMoreCondition"  [(ngModel)]="ngForm.oneMoreCondition" (ngModelChange)="changed($event, 'oneMoreCondition')" > theReportInjury<br>

      </div>


    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!canSubmit">Submit</button>


</div>
```

Then In your component.ts file

```
  theChkAcceptTerms: boolean;
  theInsuredType: boolean;
  theReportInjury: boolean;
  oneMoreCondition: boolean;
  canSubmit: boolean;
  ngForm = {}

  changed(status: boolean, control: string ){

    switch(control) { 
        case 'theChkAcceptTerms': { 
           this.theChkAcceptTerms = status
            break; 
        } 
        case 'theInsuredType': { 
            this.theChkAcceptTerms = status
            break; 
        } 
        case 'theReportInjury': { 
            this.theReportInjury = status
            break; 
        } 
        case 'oneMoreCondition': { 
           this.oneMoreCondition = status
            break; 
        } 
        default: { 
            break; 
        } 
    }
    if(this.theChkAcceptTerms &&  this.theChkAcceptTerms  &&   this.theReportInjury &&  this.oneMoreCondition){
      this.canSubmit = true;
    }else{
      this.canSubmit = false;
    }


  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But my form consists of several accordians. So the purpose of this button is to move onto the next accordion (i.e. the next section of the same form)

Comment: Then just don't make it type="submit". You can define your button behavior to go to a specific element by ID on the page same as you would in HTML

Answer (score 0):

if theChkAcceptTerms is a boolean variable then try with

```
<button [disabled]="!theChkAcceptTerms || theInsuredType.invalid ||  theReportInjury.invalid">
```

Comment: When I use this, & choose options from the radio button groups, the button is enabled without touching the checkbox